# how to remove small contour from the frame?

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, contour

I have written the program to detect the object in the water(swimming pool). But I am getting lot of other contours like as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ejeg.png). But this is the actual [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBbbQ.jpg). Please help me to get rid of other unwanted contours detected in the video. Below is the code that I have written.

```
 #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
 #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

 #include <iostream>
 #include <stdio.h>

 using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;

 string window_name = "Captured rectangle block";
 RNG rng(12345);
 double fps;
 int thresh = 100;

 int main( int argc, const char** argv )
 {
    VideoCapture cap("IMGP2850.MOV"); // open the video file for reading
    if ( !cap.isOpened() )  // if not success, exit program
    {
         cout << "Cannot open the video file" << endl;
         return -1;
    }
    fps = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS); //get the frames per seconds of the video
    cout << "Frame per seconds : " << fps << endl;
    double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    Size S(dWidth,dHeight);

    while(1)
    {

        Mat frame;
        Mat threshold_output;
        int skip_frame = 4;
        while(skip_frame)
        {
            printf("inside while loop\n");
            bool bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video
            skip_frame--;
            if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
            {
                cout << "Cannot read the frame from video file" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }

        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        if( frame.empty() )
        { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }

        std::vector<Rect> faces;
        Mat frame_gray;

        cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
        equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray);
        blur( frame_gray, frame_gray, Size(3,3) );

        vector<vector<Point> > contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        printf("before finding countrs\n");
        threshold( frame_gray, threshold_output, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY );
        findContours( threshold_output, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));
        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
        vector<Rect> boundRect( contours.size() );
        vector<Point2f>center( contours.size() );
        vector<float>radius( contours.size() );

//      contours.resize(contours.size());
        printf("after finding countrs\n");
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
        {   

                printf("inside for loop\n");
                approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
                printf("after poly\n");
                boundRect[i] = boundingRect( Mat(contours_poly[i]) );
                printf("after bondrec\n");
                minEnclosingCircle( (Mat)contours_poly[i], center[i], radius[i] );
        }
        Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( threshold_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );
        for( unsigned int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
        {
            Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
            drawContours( drawing, contours_poly, i, color, 1, 8, vector<Vec4i>(), 0, Point() );
            rectangle( drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), color, 2, 8, 0 );
            circle( drawing, center[i], (int)radius[i], color, 2, 8, 0 );
        }

        /// Show in a window
        namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
        imshow( "Contours", drawing );
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; }
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Please, save your intermediate images for one frame and show them here. Perhaps you could filter out noise from `threshold_output` by applying some morphological transformations. Next filter the contours, and remove anything that's too small. (based on area for example) Are you looking for some specific object? Use its features to classify the contours.

Comment: Think about it in a way that you need to filter the image first (to get connected edges) then find largest contour. Here is your object